# PHP Copy and Rename File

Tags: php, html

I have a file I'm attempting to move and Im able to do so, however I can't seem to change the filename exactly how I need it.

```
$file1 = "/../../../../../../rooms.GENRE.FILENAME/FILENAMEentry.html";
$newfile1 = "/../../../../creative/$path/ $dir entry.html";
copy($file1, $newfile1);
```

`$dir` is the variable with the name of the file I'm calling.
this returns the file name as `FILENAME entry.html` and I need the space between them removed.

I've tried it without the space as in

`$direntry.html` and that moves and creates the file but just names it .html

Basically I'm replacing where it says `FILENAMEentry.html` (the capitalized portion) with the name of the filename in `$dir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using concatenation:

```
$newfile1 = "/../../../../creative/$path/" . $dir . 'entry.html';
```

Comment: Thank you Marat it was the concatenation I wasn't sure about in how to write it that I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $dir works while echoing but you have space and if you write them together the word would be `$direntry` which will be ambiguous for the interpreter so use concatenation.
change

```
$newfile1 = "/../../../../creative/$path/ $dir entry.html";
```

to

```
$newfile1 = "/../../../../creative/$path/".$dir."entry.html";
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense and it was the concatenation I was missing. Thank you Danyal. Will accept answer in 5 minutes when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out these [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

This should work fine:

```
$file1 = "/../../../../../../rooms.GENRE.FILENAME/FILENAMEentry.html";
$newfile1 = "/../../../../creative/$path/".$dir."entry.html";

if (!copy($file1, $newfile1)) {
    echo "failed to copy file.";
}
```

---

> **Stephen Clay**
>
> ```
> <?php 
> "{$str1}{$str2}{$str3}"; // one concat = fast
>   $str1. $str2. $str3;   // two concats = slow
> ?>
> ```
>
> Use double quotes to concat more than two strings instead of multiple '.' operators.  PHP is forced to re-concatenate with every '.' operator.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#60035)

Comment: Thank you for this resource, I'm looking through it now and appreciate it, you are correct that it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

`$newfile1 = "/../../../../creative/$path/{$dir}entry.html";`